# Linux: refresh menu after having registered .desktop file

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I've created a menu item using `xdg-desktop-menu install mycompany-myapp.desktop`. Unfortunately, the menu item does not occur immediately on Ubuntu 11.10, but I need to log out and in again. Is there a possibility to force a menu refresh, so it occurs immediately?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't know what caused the changes, but now when I invoke `xdg-desktop-menu install mycompany-myapp.desktop` or `xdg-desktop-menu uninstall mycompany-myapp.desktop` the menu is automatically refreshed.

Comment: `/usr/bin/xdg-desktop-menu` is shell script. seems `update-desktop-database ~/.local/share/applications` did the job. (if .desktop in that dir).<br>
gnome seems also auto-refresh (after search in all apps)

Comment: Both of these didn't work on Crostini on Chromebook. It may very well that we need to either search or logout and -in  after the change.

Answer (score 10):

`xdg-desktop-menu` has an `forceupdate` option according to the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xdg-desktop-menu).

Comment: "This command is only useful if the last call to xdg-desktop-menu included the `--noupdate` option."

Answer (score 2):

Possibly same reason mine suddenly started working

I realised my .desktop file wasn't visible to group or all. I did a chmod 644 on it and it now refreshs instantly.